# Angular2 'blockquote-reverse' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a element tag provided by bootstrap 3.3.6 and when use that in my component view, it throws me the error as unknown element.

any idea how to fix this?

```
error getting is 'blockquote-reverse' is not a known element

html view where blockquote-reverse is provided in bootstrap:

<blockquote-reverse>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <footer>Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
</blockquote-reverse>
```

When I do I am getting `Error in app/views/footer.component.html:2:81 caused by: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
<blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
  <p>Angular2 have a simplified functionality</p>
  <footer>This is what we can<cite title="Source Title">Anirudha Das</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

I can avoid this by not using  but I really understand why angular2 is behaving this/

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: added html view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should be using `.blockquote-reverse` as class name and not as an element name:

```
<blockquote class="blockquote blockquote-reverse">
  ...
</blockquote>
```

More info [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#blockquote-options)

Edit:

Also your **footer.component** it's calling himself recursively

Comment: when do do you suggestion I am getting more horrible error. see my question again. I edited it.

Comment: The first problem was resolved by your answer and second problem was coming because I was using <footer> as angular selector to select my footer component as well as inside my footer comonent html the bootstrap <footer> tag was there. so it was going in infinite loop

Comment: @AniruddhaDas just edited the answer, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

you should use this:

```
<blockquote class="blockquote blockquote-reverse">
  <p class="m-b-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

per the [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#reverse-layout)